# html css js animation at start not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i saw a youtube video this is the link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ak37WrbSDg

so it basically has a animation at the start when u go into the website, which used span text. i tried to modify it and use image however it didnt work when i used image. this is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="image-slider">
            <div class="left leftright" >
                <div class="leftmain" style="background-image: url(images/left.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right leftright">
                <div class="main" style="background-image: url(images/right-bike.jpg);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        
    </div>

    <header>
        <h4>hello world</h4>
    </header>
    

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the css code

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header 
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header h4 
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 1rem;

}

.intro
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 1s;

}

.right
{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    right: -990px;
    
}


.right > div
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.left
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -990px;
}

.left > div
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100%;
    widt: 100%;
    
    
}

.right.active
{
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.left.active
{
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.image-slider.fade 
{
    bottom: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease-in-out  0.5s;
}
```

this is the js script

```
let intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
let image = document.querySelectorAll('.leftright')

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>
{
    setTimeout(()=>
    {
        image.forEach((div, index)=>
        {
            setTimeout(()=>
            {
                div.classList.add('active');
            })
        })
    })

    setTimeout(()=>
    {
        image.forEach((div, index)=>
        {
            div.classList.remove('active');
            div.classList.add('fade');

        })
    })

    setTimeout(()=>
    {
        intro.style.top = '-100vh';
    })
})
```

so when u go in the website, the image which is split in half, should come in from both side and then go up togather but when i used the live server the whole thing is blank, can someone help

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that the file isn't available on the server, or at least isn't in the directory you specify in the code. If you hit F12 and look in the browser's console, I'm thinking you'll probably see some "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the browser is executing all changes to the UI at once. The left and right `div` elements containing the background images are transitioning in and then the top of the `.intro` element is set to the `-100vh` position. The browser is executing all of these UI changes in and refreshing/repainting the client area of the browser window after all changes.

Here's a JavaScript/CSS/HTML combination that achieves the output you stated: images come together from the left and right and then after they meet, the whole intro element moves upwards out of the viewport.

```js
const intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
const leftRightContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.leftright');
const leftContainer = document.querySelector('.leftright.left');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // 'transitionend' event handler function
  const transitionendHandler = () => {
    intro.classList.add("move-up");
    leftContainer.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionendHandler);
  };
  // Add 'transitionend' event handler
  leftContainer.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionendHandler);
  // Trigger transition
  setTimeout(() => {
    leftRightContainers.forEach((elem, index) => {
      elem.classList.add('active', 'fade');
    });
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header h4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 1rem;
}

.intro {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: top ease-in-out 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.intro.move-up {
  top: -100%;
}

.leftright {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.leftright.left {
  left: -100%;
}

.leftright.right {
  left: 100%;
}

.leftright.active {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.leftright.left.active {
  left: 0;
}

.leftright.right.active {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.leftright .img-container {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-slider.fade {
  bottom: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="image-slider">
    <div class="leftright left">
      <div class="img-container" style="background-image: url(https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic3.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftright right">
      <div class="img-container" style="background-image: url(https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/building-blocks/gallery/images/pic2.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h4>hello world</h4>
```

Note: There's a small delay the first time the code in the following snippet is executed. This is the result of the time it takes for the browser to download the images into the background of the `.image-container` elements. Re-running the snippets works as expected since the images are cached. A fix to this issue is to run the left-right-move-up intro animation after the images are downloaded into the image container elements. That is, set up an image 'onLoad' event listener for each image container and then start the intro animation.